# regexp_extract not working

Tags: regex, hive

I have the string
Created RSA Key 1234 from Intelligent Expense ID 54678||||||"

and I need to extract 54678 in Hive QL. I am using this

```
select description,regexp_extract(description,'ID\s(\d*)\|') as cctkey from smartmatching limit 10
```

I tested the regex and it looks fine. But hive does not return any output for me. It is showing NULL. Can somebody help

Comment: try this :- `regexp_extract(description,'ID\s(\d*)\|', 1)`

Comment: Even this is returning null for me . Am I missing anything

Comment: the previous question i answered was working for you..have you modified the query?

Comment: Yeah @rock321987. Its the same one, it is working fine in regex101.com, but even after the modified regexp_extract you gave above, it is showing null (select description,regexp_extract(description,'ID\s(\d*)\|', 1) as cctkey from smartmatching limit 10)

Comment: use some string(like you provided an example) instead of description for checking

Comment: I tried this. select regexp_extract('Created RSA Key 1234 from Intelligent Expense ID 54678||||||','ID\s(\d*)\|',1) as cctkey from smartmatching limit 10. But this also returns null

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109593/discussion-between-rock321987-and-adithya-kumar).

Answer (score 2):

You need to escape the `\s`, `\d` and `\|`. It should be

```
ID\\s(\\d*)\\|
```